# high z-index on element within jquery ui dialog fails to appear above dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to put a custom dropdown into a div that I use as a jquery UI modal. The problem is that when the dropdown is revealed, it appears inside the modal—overflowing the modals height, giving the modal a scrollbar and not showing the entire contents of the dropdown as I would expect (with the `z-index` set to a very high number) outside the modal.

It will make more sense when you see it: I've made a simplified ugly version at [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ukoqup/2/edit). Why is the z-index no good here? Thanks!

Comment: I can't see the problem on jsbin, but z-index doesn't work on statically positioned elements. Try adding `position: relative` to the elements that have a z-index.

Comment: @bfavaretto okay. I'll take a look at that. Where don't you see the problem. You have to click the div that says select a state to get the "dropdown"

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question. Maybe you're looking for `overflow: visible` on the container/dialog?

Comment: yes! I just figured that out and was reporting back here to post it. Thanks! Would you like to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Thanks thomas, but go ahead and add your own answer. You'll certainly be able to give more details than I would!

Comment: why don't you use a normal `<select>` html tag?